# My function doesn't execute

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Enter two numbers from keyboard with at least three digits.
>
> Print the number that have the digits sum greater.

Inside of a function I have tried to print the values of variables.
The values of those variables is not printed, so I think that the function is not being executed.

```
a = input('\n Enter the first number : ' )
x = sum([a])
print('\n The sum of the digits number ' +str(x)+ ' este : %d' %x)

b = input('\n Enter the second number : ')
y = sum([b])
print('\n The sum of the digits number ' +str(y)+ ' este : %d' %y)

def sum(param):
    var = 0
    while(param != 0):
        var += (param % 10)
        print(var)
        param /=  10
        print(param)
    return var
```

Comment: Rename your function to something other than `sum` and watch what happens. That'll help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the number in as a list? also Python has a built in sum so its poor form to redefine it

Answer (score 2):

The calls to the function happen before the function is defined. Move it to the start of your program.

```
def mysum(param):
    var = 0
    while(param != 0):
        var += (param % 10)
        print(var)
        param /=  10
        print(param)
    return var

a = input('\n Enter the first number : ' )
x = mysum([a])
print('\n The sum of the digits number ' +str(x)+ ' este : %d' %x)

b = input('\n Enter the second number : ')
y = mysum([b])
print('\n The sum of the digits number ' +str(y)+ ' este : %d' %y)
```

Oh, and don't override the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) (that's why I used `mysum`).

Also, the sum of digits can be computed by using `map` and `sum`:

```
sum_of_digits = sum(int(x) for x in str(123) if x.isdigit())
```

Or as a function:

```
def sum_of_digits(numstr):
    return sum(int(x) for x in str(numstr) if x.isdigit())
```

Comment: Will `while(param != 0)` ever exit? `param` is a list. Also, you might want to cast `a` and `b` to `int`

Comment: @cricket_007 there are more quirks than that in the code. I'm only helping him with a single step. If he needs it as a one-off thing there is the last part of my answer where I provide a why to calculate the sum of a number's digit nicely.